# How to capture PowerShell output from C# using Rx

Tags: c#, powershell, system.reactive

I've written a C# extension method that invokes PowerShell asynchronously and maps the output to an Rx observable as follows.

```
public static IObservable<String> ToObservable(this PowerShell powershell)
{
    var powerShellOutputBuffer = new PSDataCollection<String>();

    var observableOutput = Observable
        .FromEventPattern<DataAddedEventArgs>(
            h => powershell.Streams.Debug.DataAdded += h,
            h => powershell.Streams.Debug.DataAdded -= h)
        .Select(ep => ((PSDataCollection<DebugRecord>)ep.Sender)[ep.EventArgs.Index].Message)
        .Merge(
            Observable.FromEventPattern<DataAddedEventArgs>(
                    h => powershell.Streams.Verbose.DataAdded += h,
                    h => powershell.Streams.Verbose.DataAdded -= h)
                .Select(ep => ((PSDataCollection<VerboseRecord>)ep.Sender)[ep.EventArgs.Index].Message))
        .Merge(
            Observable.FromEventPattern<DataAddedEventArgs>(
                    h => powershell.Streams.Error.DataAdded += h,
                    h => powershell.Streams.Error.DataAdded -= h)
                .Select(ep => ((PSDataCollection<ErrorRecord>)ep.Sender)[ep.EventArgs.Index].Exception.ToString()))
        .Merge(
            Observable.FromEventPattern<DataAddedEventArgs>(
                    h => powerShellOutputBuffer.DataAdded += h,
                    h => powerShellOutputBuffer.DataAdded -= h)
                .Select(ep => ((PSDataCollection<String>)ep.Sender)[ep.EventArgs.Index]));

    Task<PSDataCollection<PSObject>> invokePowerShellTask = null;

    return Observable.Create<String>(
        observer =>
        {
            var subscription = observableOutput.Subscribe(observer);

            if (invokePowerShellTask == null)
            {
                invokePowerShellTask = Task.Factory.FromAsync(powershell.BeginInvoke((PSDataCollection<PSObject>)null, powerShellOutputBuffer), powershell.EndInvoke);
                invokePowerShellTask.ContinueWith(a => { powershell.Dispose(); });
            }

            invokePowerShellTask.ContinueWith(
                a =>
                {
                    if (a.Exception == null)
                    {
                        observer.OnCompleted();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        observer.OnError(a.Exception);
                    }
                });

            return subscription;
        });
}
```

The PowerShell invocation should happen on subscription to support sequential chaining via the concat operator (ex. `observableOperation1.concat(observableOperation2).subscribe(...)`). Additionally, invocation should only happen once to support scenarios where there may be multiple subscribers observing at various points in the invocation timeline. When the invocation completes all appropriate resources should be disposed of and the observable should complete or error.

The above code works, but seems very gnarly. I can't help but feel that there is a better way to do this. Is there a simpler way to accomplish this by using the built in Rx operators or perhaps use of the async/await pattern.

Comment: I would need to think harder about it but wouldn't this be more intuitive with Observable.FromAsync kicking off the Powershell task, followed by the error/verbose streams, going nto .Publish to make it hot?

Comment: @Sentinel If you kick off the PowerShell task before wiring up the error/verbose streams, I think there might be a chance that some of the initial output could be missed.

Comment: No observable.fromasync only fires the task on subscribe

Comment: That may work, I'll give it a try!